# QT6 QThread doesn't start correctly or is forced to be destroyed immediately after starting

Tags: python, qthread, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm trying to develop a GUI with pyside6 and one of the button functions takes too long to execute, which usually causes the interface to lag without being able to add interactive information, but when I try to multithread it, I always get various errors

```
class ThreadClass(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, index=0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.is_running = True
        self.any_signal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        print("线程开始.....", self.index)
        cnt = 0
        while (True):
            cnt += 1
            if cnt == 99:
                cnt = 0
            self.any_signal.emit(cnt)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print("线程结束.....", self.index)
        self.terminate()

    def predict(self,pic_path):
```

This is after I made several attempts, the thread could start running, but immediately ran down after executing the first task.

`self.any_signal.emit(cnt) AttributeError: 'PyQt6.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'emit'`

```
class ThreadClass(QThread):

    any_signal = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, parent=None,index=0):
        super(ThreadClass,self).__init__(parent)
        self.index = index
        self.is_running = True


    def run(self):
        print("线程开始.....",self.index)
        cnt = 0
        while (True):
            cnt += 1
            if cnt == 99: cnt = 0
            self.any_signal.emit(cnt)

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        print("线程结束.....",self.index)
        self.terminate()

    def predict(self,pic_path):
```

This is an earlier version that doesn't even get into the threads correctly

Comment: Your codes and question have many issues. First of all, signals **must** be declared at class level, so your first code is wrong. Then, it's unclear if you're using PySide or PyQt (the question has tags for both, but doesn't include any import in its codes), and you will certainly get issues if you try to use them together. Also, as the [documentation **clearly** says](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#terminate), you shall *NOT* call `QThread.terminate()` unless you *really* know what you're doing. Finally, you mention "various errors", but you only showed us *one*, and your code is not an [mre].

Comment: ‘from PySide6.QtCore import QThread, Signal

class PredictThread(QThread):
    result_signal = Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, pic_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.pic_path = pic_path

    def run(self):
        result = predict(self.pic_path)
        self.result_signal.emit(result)’

Comment: Thank you very much, in fact after I tried your suggestion and made the changes, it worked correctly

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using Pyside6 and made a mistake in QThread.

After debugging, the correct way to write it is as follows. Although I am not currently able to understand the mechanism of inter-thread interactions in great detail, this code does work and I hope it helps.

QThread class part:

```
class PredictThread(QThread):
result_signal = Signal(object)
text_signal = Signal(str)
progress_signal = Signal(int)

def __init__(self, pic_path, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.pic_path = pic_path

def run(self):
    sys.stdout.write = self.write_to_signal
    result = predict(self.pic_path, self.progress_signal)
    self.result_signal.emit(result)


def write_to_signal(self, text):
    self.text_signal.emit(text)
```

The trigger button:

```
       if btnName == "commandLinkButton_3":
        pic_path = widgets.lineEdit.text()
        self.predict_thread = PredictThread(pic_path)
        self.predict_thread.result_signal.connect(self.handle_result)
        self.predict_thread.text_signal.connect(self.handle_text) 
       self.predict_thread.progress_signal.connect(self.update_progress) 
        self.predict_thread.start()
```